# List of guava Multimap

Tags: java, multimap

Is to possible to create a list of guava Multimap?

I created a regular Multimap as so, but was not able to create as list of Multimaps

```
Multimap<String, Integer> map = ArrayListMultimap.create();
```

Comment: Unclear: do you need a _filled_ list of multimaps?

Comment: Yes it is. What didn't work for you?

Comment: Created empty initially.

Comment: @Spacko which should be fine, did you not intend to do so? try doing a `put` in the map in that case.

Comment: The about code works, but I could not create List<Multimap<String, Integer>> map =... 
I do not know how to initialise

Comment: You make a list just like any other.  `List<Multimap<String, Integer>> map = new ArrayList<>();`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have initialized the `MultiMap` precisely using:

```
Multimap<String, Integer> map = ArrayListMultimap.create();
```

Now if you tend to implement a `java.util.List` of such a MultiMap, you can simply initialise it as:

```
java.util.List<MultiMap<String, Integer>> listOfMap = new ArrayList<>(); 
// array list initialisation within which the multimap can be initialised using previous code

listOfMap.add(map);
```

Comment: Working, thank you. I had to change MultiMap to Multimap